# Memory management using blocking but in vain

Tags: machine-learning, memory

I have trained a classifier named `c` and want to apply it to testing set. However, due to the huge size of testing set, I have to make prediction in blocks/groups to save memory. Here is my code:

```
testFile = OpenRead["test.txt"];
resultFile = OpenWrite["prediction.txt"];
WriteLine[resultFile, "id,label"];

Monitor[
  Do[Block[{records, testX, testY},
     blockEnd = Min[blockBegin + blockSize - 1, totalLength - 1];
     actualBlockSize = blockEnd - blockBegin + 1;
     (*records is read from the file stream*)
     records = 
      Table[StringSplit[ReadLine[testFile], " "], actualBlockSize];
     Monitor[
      testX = Table[
        SparseArray[#[[1]] -> #[[2]] & /@ 
          Map[Read[StringToStream[#], Number] &, 
           StringSplit[Drop[records[[i]], 1], ":"], {2}], maxcol, 
         0], {i, 1, actualBlockSize}], 
      ProgressIndicator[i, {1, actualBlockSize}]];
     testY = c[#, "Probabilities"][1] & /@ testX;

     WriteLine[resultFile, 
        ToString[#[[1]], CForm] <> "," <> ToString[#[[2]], CForm]] & /@
       Transpose@{Range[blockBegin, blockEnd], testY}
     ], {blockBegin, 0, totalLength - 1, blockSize}];
  , ProgressIndicator[blockBegin, {0, totalLength}]
  ];
Close[testFile];
Close[resultFile];
```

I expect that when I execute the `Do` loop, memory cost should be stable. However, in reality, memory cost is continuously increasing, and the tendency is that my RAM will be run out. I expect that `Block` will clear memory occupied by variables `records`, `testX` and `testY` after execution every time, but it seems not.
I still can't find any solution to this problem...

Comment: does the same thing happen with Module instead of Block?  Any special reason you are using Block instead of Module btw?

Comment: @Nasser I have tried Module[] but got the same performance checked in task manager in win10. No special reason indeed. I even tried Clear[] those temporary variables before the end of Block[] but it also cost too much memory.

Comment: May be you can try also `$HistoryLength = 0` to see if it helps.

Comment: I have tried at the very beginning of my code, just after setting my working directory. But unfortunately, it does not work, since the code shown above is as **an independent program block**. Should I set in **this program block** again?

Comment: I think $HistoryLength = 0 works on global. But you could always try. It is hard to suggest something, since one can't run your code as is. If you can make a MWE that does not require special files that only you have, may be someone can try better then. Otherwise may be someone else can spot what the issue is by looking at the code. I can't.

Comment: @Nasser OK I know. To read others' code (especially those without notes) is quite an annoying thing. But I haven't find a proper way to adjust my code (regret my poor coding technique). I have upload my whole code and data on [google drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oBJYAYYjO3uQkcap5oDdLsdzh1rhi0gK) if you need.

Comment: You could also try explicitly clearing the block variable at end of iterations? As in `ClearAll[records, testX, testY]` and any other one used in there at each iteration and not needed any more, to see if this helps.

Comment: @Nasser Seems to be still increasing after adding `ClearAll[records, testX, testY]`... I just guess that WriteLine[] will generate temporary backup that cannot be cleaned by setting `$HistoryLength = 0`? How to solve this problem?

Comment: And I even don't know whether `WriteLine[]` will have any side effect to increase memory cost...